# How to get the image from parsed JSON into ListView

Tags: android, json, bitmap, bitmapfactory

My problem is: i'm trying to convert byte[] into image. The byte[] comes from JSON and it's in this format:

"4oCwUE5HDQoaCgAAAA1JSERSAAAAfwAAAFAIBgAAADBHwqrDsAAAAAlwSFlzAAAAJwAAACcBKgnigJhPAAAgAElEQVR4xZPCrMK9ecWSZcOZfcOfw7c5w5vCvW/CqXp..." it goes for another 100 lines.

The code where the problem occurs:

```
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        // again some simple validation around the returned string
        if(jsonString != null && jsonString.length() != 0) // checking string returned from service to grab id
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {   
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                // you need to store the results somewhere and pass it on to the player list
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                byte[] image = jsonObject.getString("image").getBytes();
                String base64 = jsonObject.getString("image");
                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    String images = new String(decodedString);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = Utils.getBitmapFromString(images);
                    decodedByte.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    Log.d("DECODEDBYTE IS: ", decodedByte.toString());
                    if (decodedByte != null) {
                        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
                }

                map.put("name", name.toString());
                map.put("image", image);
                Log.d("JSON OBJECTS:", jsonObject.toString());
                Log.d("WHATS IN MAP:", map.toString());

                playersList.add(map);
            }
```

Before I was getting NULL value at decodedByte (Bitmap) now it's telling me:

> Unable to decode stream: FileNotFoundException.

I'm struggling with this two days already and can't get this working!

Any ideas of what might be wrong?

[EDIT] These are values from the debbuger:

> jsonString    "[{"id":"16","clubid":"1","name":"Theo
>   Walcott","password":"0000","image":"4oCwUE5HDQoaCgAAAA1JSERS...WeKAsGfDngAAAABJRU5Ewq5CYOKAmg==","lastupdated":"2013-08-22
>   09:31:58","isDeleted":"0"}]" (id=830043725448)     map    HashMap 
>   (id=830043562472)  name   "Theo Walcott" (id=830043434760)
>   parameters    ArrayList  (id=830043725168)     arg0   String[0] 
>   (id=830043671992)  stream ByteArrayOutputStream  (id=830043562528)
>   decodedString (id=830045128536)    images "‰PNG\r\n\n

And the LogCat:

> 10-30 14:02:57.717: D/JSON OBJECTS:(14452):
>   {"id":"24","image":"4oCwUE5HDQoaCgA...CFcKpD8WTw5 10-30 14:02:57.717:
>   D/WHATS IN MAP:(14452): {image=[B@428e6d20, name=Ryo Miyaichi} 10-30
>   14:03:03.747: E/BitmapFactory(14452): Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
>   10-30 14:03:03.747: I/System.out(14452): resolveUri failed on bad
>   bitmap uri

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Do you want to save the image to the filesystem or only show it on screen?

Comment: show it on the screen (ImageView)

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);

if(bitmap != null){
   ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
   imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

This is how you should decode a `String` to a `Bitmap` from the response you get from json.

Comment: Where did you get the Base64 file?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean.. but the Base64 is parameter from json file.

Comment: android.util.Base64

public class 
Base64
extends Object

java.lang.Object 
   ↳ android.util.Base64 
You mean this?

Comment: Yes, so you are using Base64 from android lib. I use another Base64, give me a sec and maybe I can find the link where you can download that class and use that one instead.

Comment: Copy and paste this source code into a class that you name Base64, and use this one instead. Tell me how it goes.
http://hi-android.info/src/android/util/Base64.java.html

Comment: still getting null... i'm getting depressed :(

Comment: Are you using the approach exact as I told you? Also, are you sure it is a valid image? What type of image is it you are sending from server?

Comment: Yes, Im calling the Base64 class from my package. And the image is in PNG format.

Comment: Very strange. There are some parts in your code that you shouldn't use, but if you don't do it anymore, I don't know what the problem is :/

Comment: Does the adapter make difference? Cuz I'm using SimpleAdapter. Trying now to change this for BaseAdapter.

Comment: No it doesn't matter at all. All you need to do is to get the String from the response, call this String base64 and use the approach I gave you. Log if bitmap == null. If it is, something's strange mate.